# mysql - Using Group By

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I am trying to write a mysql query for an app I'm developing for android.

I have a database that has a `bill_content` table and a `products` table 
I want to select top 10 most sold products.

This is a minimal version of what I have, but it's all I need to get an answer here.

`bill_content` table has the columns: `id`, `id_product`, `quantity` (id_product and quantity here can be duplicate because this table is larger, containing id_bill and other information)

`products` table has the columns: `id`, `name`

```
SELECT products.name AS Product,
       bill_content.quantity AS Quantity

FROM bill_content, products
WHERE bill_content.id = products.id
ORDER BY bill_content.quantity DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Of course this returns a table of 2 rows containing all the products and their quantity in the `bill_content` table, but there are duplicates and I need to make sum of their quantity and display them as a single row.

Thank you in advance.

**ANSWERED**
This could be done using `GROUP BY` as Gordon Linoff said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a `group by`.  You should also learn to use proper explicit `join` syntax:

```
SELECT p.name AS Product,
       SUM(bc.quantity) AS Quantity
FROM bill_content bc JOIN
     products p
     ON bc.id = p.id
GROUP BY p.name
ORDER BY SUM(bc.quantity) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Thank you, I used the JOIN syntax also. Will accept this when accepting becomes available.